# Trace stolen android mobile

Tags: lost-phone

I lost my mobile on 26th March, 2013. I didn't install any tracking apps and they removed my sim card from my mobile.  Is possible to track my mobile using the device ID? Is there any Unique ID for android mobiles? Is my device id logged with my associated Google account? contacting Google support works? if yes then how to contact.

OS: android 4.0.4 ICS
Model: Micromax A110 [canvas 2]

Thanks,
Haridharan. R

Comment: Have you checked with the [lost-phone tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/lost-phone/info) and the "key-questions" linked there? That should get you started. But with the SIMCard removed, chances get lower. If at least WiFi is on and your device logged in to your Google account, you can use the "Plan B" alternative described in the tag wiki.

Comment: Please remove your IMEI for your own security sake! Publishing it, anyone can crawl the web and find a way to unlock the said IMEI from a mobile network.... just saying...

Answer (score 1):

You can remotely install an app like [Plan B](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.lookout.labs.planb) or [AndroidLost](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidlost&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwMiwiY29tLmFuZHJvaWRsb3N0Il0.) from the Play Store website to try to recover the device's location.  Your device has to be un-wiped for this to work, i.e., your Google Account has to be active on the device and it needs to be registered with the Play Store.

Other than that you are likely out of luck unless you have Google Latitude enabled or some other security software.  If you know your IMEI or other device identifiers you could try giving that to law enforcement or the the phone companies in your area, but in many areas there is no sort of coordinated effort to keep stolen phones from being re-used.

Comment: In case you weren't aware: http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/1711/can-a-moderator-delete-a-quite-popular-question-to-prevent-discussion-of-a-close